# Calculation Of Integral Related To Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Let's evaluate the following integral. Many trials but no success.
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{\sin nx}{(1+\pi^{x})\sin x}dx$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Fix $x=-x \implies dx=-dx$

$$I=-\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\dfrac{\sin n(-x)}{(1+(\pi)^{-x})\sin (-x)} dx$$

$$I= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{\sin n(-x)}{(1+(\pi)^{-x})\sin (-x)} dx$$

$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{\pi^x \sin n(x)}{(\pi^x+1)\sin x} dx$$

Add this to $I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{\sin nx}{(1+\pi^{x})\sin x}dx$

$$2I= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin nx}{\sin x} \dfrac{\pi^x+1}{1+\pi^x}dx$$

If you have $\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx$ and $f(x) $ is even, the same integral can be written as $2\int_0^af(x)dx$. I believe you can do the further caculations.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: The technique was thought by [him](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/16823/isomorphism). Credits to him.:)

Comment: Why not cancel the  $\dfrac{\pi^x+1}{1+\pi^x}$ in the last equation?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Yes, that gets cancelled. But to make OP understand about how $I$ becomes $\int \dfrac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$, I kept it as it is.:)